# config Mass transit for both Kafka and RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I want to use Mass Transit with RabbitMQ  and Kafka for message broker.
and in deployment phase can decide which one be used for transporting messages.

I know what's ConsumeContext,ISendEndpointProvider, or IPublishEndpoint. And according of  [the link](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/riders/) this Interfaces shared between RabbitMQ  and Kafka for publishing messages and consuming that.
I configured both RabbitMQ and Kafka in startup of my .Net Core App and by appSetting in deployment phase can decide which one must be register.

this approach is correct for having and configure both Kafka and RabbitMq in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using MassTransit, Kafka is a *Rider* which is configured along with a bus – and the bus still requires a supported transport. If you have RabbitMQ, that would be your bus transport, and the Kafka Rider would exist alongside the bus using the bus for publishing and sending messages.

With Kafka, messages can only be consumed or produced – they cannot be published, nor can they be sent. The `ITopicProducer<T>` interface is used to produce messages to Kafka topics.

Calling `Publish` or `Send` on the `ConsumeContext` will publish or send those messages to the rider's bus (which may be RabbitMQ, or any supported transport included the InMemory transport). Producing messages to Kafka topics must be done using the `ITopicProducer<T>` (which may be injected as a dependency to the consumer).

> You can't "switch out" RabbitMQ with Kafka as the two services are very different.

Comment: thanks a lot. but I read about Kafka that all articles said Kafka has an alternative for traditional message brokers such as Rabbit. I guess can't use Kafka as a Message broker in Mass Transit framework. Mass Transit  used Kafka as a Rider? is it correct?

Comment: Correct, as stated in my response, Kafka is a Rider with MassTransit. Kafka is _NOT_ a replacement for a traditional message broker. Kafka is a log writer with an API.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson Isn't it possible to support Kafka as bus transport too?

Comment: @SaiKiranMandhala no, it isn't.